# Normalizing JSON response from server before updating Redux state

Tags: python, django, redux, json-deserialization

It's my preferred paradigm (and probably everyone's) that the server remains unopinionated about serializing its JSON response as it doesn't care which client is consuming it. Said another way, my django JSON payload is written in snake case as per standards. Before this can update the state in my Redux store the keys should be mapped to camel case as per Javascript standards. The python developers don't believe this is worth the effort, which he has a fair point but it just feels wrong not following convention.

How should this be handled??

Comment: Depends on the way you handle server responses, but a common way is using a middleware and something like [humps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/humps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I usually have is a middleware that handles all my fetch requests, in there I can intercept the response and transform the keys to camelCase using Humps.

```
// fetchMiddleware.js
export default ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => (action) => {
  if (typeof action === 'function') {
    return action(dispatch, getState);
  }

  const { promise, types, ...rest } = action;

  // this middleware expects a promise object in the action,
  // the object contains all configurations to send the request to
  // the server, if no promise is defined then it just ignores this action
  if (!promise) {
    return next(action);
  }

  return fetch(promise.url, promise)
    .then(response => Promise.resolve(humps.camelizeKeys(response)))
    .then(data => dispatch({ type: types[1], data }))
    .catch(error => dispatch({ type: types[2], error }));
}
```

Then in some component or anywhere else, the action will be dispatched like this:

```
store.dispatch({
  types: ['BEFORE_REQUEST', 'REQUEST_SUCCESS', 'REQUEST_FAIL'],
  promise: {
    url: 'some/api.json',
    params: { x, y },
  },
});
```

I usually have an utility to handle the fetch, but this will give you the idea on how to deal with camelCase transforming.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a special parser and/or renderer to switch back and forth between camel case and snake case. If you're using [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/), you can use the `JSONRenderer` to create a new subclass such as `CamelCaseJSONRenderer` so that it automatically switches back and forth.

At base, you'll want to implement a function that looks something like this:

```
def to_camelcase(string, lower_first_char=True):
    """Takes snakecase string and converts to camelcase."""
    camelize = ''.join(char.capitalize() for char in word.split('_'))
    result = (camelize[0].lower() + result[1:]) if lower_first else camelize
    return result

def parse(data, lower_first=True):
    """Camelcase the keys of a dictionary or items of a list."""
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        result = {to_camelcase(k): parse(v) for k, v in data.items()}
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        result = [parse(item) for item in data]
    else:
        result = data
    return result
```

You could then run these functions in the customized `CamelCaseJSONRenderer` and add the renderer to your views. That way all python objects are snakecase on the back and camelcase in your javascript.